elasticsearch get the median excluding zero
I am trying to get the median excluding zero in elasticsearch. I have the following query: the call_median is getting the median from the field call_cnt. However, we would like to exclude all the zero values of the call_cnt. Please let me know how I can adjust it?
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "match": {
            "abc": "dfffss"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "created_time": {
              "gte": 1727827200000,
              "lte": 1728259200000
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_label": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "rate",
        "size": 10000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "api_usage": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "created_time",
            "calendar_interval": "week",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "total_call_sum": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "call_cnt"
              }
            },
            "call_median": {
              "percentiles": {
                "field": "call_cnt",
                "percents": [50]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

